# dnnAlert is scrolling to top of page when OK button is clicked

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, dotnetnuke, alert

I am using dnnAlert in my DNN 7.02 website ( dnnAlert is a jQuery UI plugin for dnnAlert that is included in regular DNN install) in place of regular alert, but the problem is that when I click on OK button, the page automatically scrolls to the top, which is very annoying.

How can I prevent the automatic scrolling?

```
 $.dnnAlert({
        text: 'Copied code to clipboard',
        dialogClass: 'dnnFormPopup',
        title: 'Copy Successful',
        modal:false
    });
```

The OK button is rendered with following html.

```
<button class="dnnPrimaryAction" type="button">Ok</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a lot of time trying to get JQUI dialogs to work properly in DNN 7.
I expect the problem you are having is related to setting

modal: false

I have found that using a straight JQUI dialog works if the crucial element:

dialogClass: 'dnnFormPopup dnnClear'

is added.
JC